# Weird message about Wireless keyboard very low in power when changing to tablet mode (Ubuntu 18.04 on HP Pavilion x360)

Tags: hp, touchscreen, digitalpen

I have a laptop HP Pavilion x360 14-cd0009la with a dual boot windows and ubuntu systems. When i am in ubuntu and convert the laptop to tablet and try to use the software keyboard in the touchscreen, Ubuntu sends a notification to the screen saying: Wireless keyboard is very low in power (1%). This device will soon stop functioning if not charged. And suddenly the touch screen just stops responding to user interaction and i have to go back to laptop mode turning back the keyboard to the front.

On a similar scenario: The laptop comes with a smart pen for Windows ink. When i try to use it in ubuntu without going into tablet mode, the touchscreen does respond to the pen input, but the message about the wireless keyboard with very low power (1%) persists.

Additional information: Ubuntu 18.04 Linux kernel 4.18.0-13-generic 64bits

On dmesg, i see a lot of message like this whenever i try to use the touchscreen with and without the pen:

i2c_hid i2c-ELAN2514:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (67/65535)

I understand that the "ELAN2514" is the touchscreen model, is that right?

What is going on with the "wireless keyboard with very low power message ? How to turn it off ? Is there a way to make my touchscreen work properly and be able to use the software keyboard in tablet mode ?

Comment: I just upgraded and began seeing this exact same message.